# JPA Hibernate remove child object of entity, connected with dual PK triggers SQL update instead of delete?

Tags: java, sql, spring, set, spring-data

I have the following table structure:

[image]

- Each chat_bot can have multiple versions.
- Each version can be deployed to environment.
- Version has dual primary key, one of which is referenced from the chat_bot table.
- Environment table only has primary keys. Two of which is referenced from the version table.

**I have the following class structure:**

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "chat_bot")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bot {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "botId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BotVersion> versions = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BotVersionPK implements Serializable {
    private String botId;
    private int version;
}


@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "chat_bot_version")
@NoArgsConstructor
@IdClass(BotVersionPK.class)
public class BotVersion {

    @Id
    private String botId;
    @Id
    private int version;

    @Type(type = "text")
    private String json;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "botId", referencedColumnName = "botId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version")
    })
    private Set<BotEnvironments> environments = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BotEnvironmentsPK implements Serializable {
    private String botId;
    private int version;
    private String environmentCode;
}

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "chat_bot_environments")
@IdClass(BotEnvironmentsPK.class)
public class BotEnvironments {
    @Id
    private String botId;
    @Id
    private int version;
    @Id
    private String environmentCode;
}
```

I use a JpaRepository< Bot, String > for loading and persisting information.

**Question:**
In case I remove an item from the "environments" Set, and persist it, Hibernate does not trigger a DELETE operation, but an UPDATE operation:

```
update chat_bot_environments set bot_id=null, version=null where bot_id=? and version=?
```

I get the following error, which is valid:

```
Column 'bot_id' cannot be null
```

Why does Hibernate JPA triggers update instead of DELETE? How could I delete a child element which is connected by a non-null PK?

Comment: Didn't you miss the cascade attribute on the environments OneToMany ?

Comment: No difference between the results.

Comment: How are you creating schema? If with sql, can you provide the scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your mapping.

1. **Joining columns are always on the child side**:

   ```
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumns({
           @JoinColumn(name = "botId", referencedColumnName = "botId"),
           @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version")
   })
   private Set<BotEnvironments> environments = new LinkedHashSet<>();
   ```

This mapping should be moved to the child (`BotEnvironments`).

2. `mappedBy` should point to the field of the same type as the entity. You have defined `mappedBy = "botId"`, but `botId` is of type `String` (it's a foreign key). This will not map the relationship between the entities.
3. Don't be afraid of bidirectional relationships. They do not cause performance overhead - actually very often they can optimize the persistence performance.

There was a couple of other small stuff that I corrected. I have omitted Lombok annotations and fetching type for brevity. Here is the proper mapping (the resulting database schema generated is the same):

**Bot**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_bot")
public class Bot {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<BotVersion> versions = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}
```

**BotVersion**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_bot_version")
@IdClass(BotVersionPK.class)
public class BotVersion {

    @Id
    private String botId;
    @Id
    private int version;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "botId", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Bot bot;

    @Type(type = "text")
    private String json;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "botVersion")
    private Set<BotEnvironments> environments = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}
```

**BotEnvironments**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_bot_environments")
@IdClass(BotEnvironmentsPK.class)
public class BotEnvironments {
    @Id
    private String botId;
    @Id
    private int version;
    @Id
    private String environmentCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "botId", referencedColumnName = "botId", insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "version", referencedColumnName = "version", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private BotVersion botVersion;

}
```

Id classes are unchanged.

Here is a simple test, that checks it works:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    // given
    BotEnvironments botEnvironments = new BotEnvironments("bid", 1, "env");
    BotEnvironments botEnvironments1 = new BotEnvironments("bid", 1, "env1");
    BotVersion botVersion = new BotVersion("bid", 1, "json", Set.of(botEnvironments, botEnvironments1));
    Bot bot = new Bot("bid", Set.of(botVersion));
    botRepository.save(bot);

    // when
    Bot savedBot = botRepository.findAll().get(0);
    savedBot.getVersions().iterator().next().getEnvironments().remove(savedBot.getVersions().iterator().next().getEnvironments().iterator().next());
    botRepository.save(savedBot);

    // then
    assertEquals(1, botEnvironmentsRepository.findAll().size());
}
```